# What is the origin of "head off" in the sense "to prevent"?

Tags: etymology

Where does the meaning of "to head off" in the sense

> :to turn back or turn aside : block, prevent
>
> // head them off at the pass
>
> // attempts to head off the imminent crisis

[(Merriam-Webster)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/head%20off)

originate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To head off (v.) seems to come from "A heading" - a direction of travel, which became a verb:

OED

> †3. Hunting. With reference to a hunted (or occasionally hunting) animal: the action of changing direction suddenly and sharply while running; doubling. Also: an instance of this. Cf. head n.1 47. ***Obsolete.***
>
> 1607   E. Topsell Hist. Foure-footed Beastes 152   *The nature of this Hare is, sometimes to leape and make headings, sometime to tread softly.*

Which then was used in a nautical context as a verb and a noun:

> **a. intransitive. To move forwards in a specified direction or towards a particular place or thing. Later also more generally: to go, make one's way. Also transitive: to follow (a course, way, etc.) in a specified direction.**
>
> 1817   A. Delano Narr. Voy. & Trav. Northern & Southern Hemispheres xxiv. 468   *I was just heading for the land, when..I saw one of my faithful sailors..making towards me with all possible exertion.*

OED has the entry:

> to head off
>
> 1. transitive.
>
> **a. To move ahead of so as to intercept, or so as to obstruct and cause to turn back or aside.**
>
> 1825   E. Mackenzie Hist. View Northumberland (ed. 2) II. 144   *The fox took towards Rotherbury Forest... Here it appears he was headed off.*

Which then gave rise to your "to prevent [something from happening]

> **b. To stop (a person or thing) from accomplishing some purpose, goal, task, etc.; (also) to anticipate and prevent; to avert.**
>
> 1866   Missionary Mag. July 232   *The Pastors..have failed..to foresee
> and head off disaster.*
>
> 2008   B. G. Ramcharan Preventative Diplomacy at UN 1   *Wherever
> feasible, everything possible should be done to head off a conflict or
> disaster.*

Answer (score 1):

According to the AHD the phrasal verb ***[head off](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/head+off)*** dates back to mid 19th century:

> Block the progress or completion of; also, intercept. For example, *They worked round the clock to head off the flu epidemic, or Try to head him off before he gets home.* [First half of 1800s]

> This expression gave rise to ***head someone off at the pass,*** which in
> Western films meant "to block someone at a mountain pass." It then
> became a general colloquialism for intercepting someone, as in Jim is
> going to the boss's office-let's head him off at the pass.